# Address location and value at address location in C

Tags: c, pointer-conversion

```
int PileInts[1024];
char *Pile = (char *)PileInts;
```

What do these two lines of code do? I am thinking that the `char *Pile = (char *)PileInts;` line creates a character named `*Pile` that gives the value of the address at `PileInts`. Am I right? Could I get a deeper explanation?

Comment: _creates a character named *Pile that gives the value of the address at PileInts_ not a character, pointer to character. This is a cast of (not really) the pointer on `int` to the pointer on `char`.

Comment: @user3365922 -- hmm, what do you mean by (not really)? That is exactly what it does. On access `PileInts` is converted to a pointer to the first element, it is the cast to `char *` and the address assigned to `Pile` (no violation of C Standard 6.5(p6) because it is allowed in 6.5(p7). See [C11 Standard - 6.5 Expressions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6))

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I meant that `int*` and `int[N]` are not exactly the same, isn't it?

Comment: Okay, gotcha, I was a bit confused at first. So `int*` being a *pointer to* `int` and the `[...]` acting as a dereference making the type `int`. You are correct, so if `p` is a pointer, then `p[N]` is the same as `*(p + N)` which is type `int`.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
int PileInts[1024];
```

creates an array object that consists of 1024 integers. The object can be accessed using the variable name `PileInts`

The line

```
char *Pile = (char *)PileInts;
```

creates a **char pointer** object and makes it point to the first char of the array object. The char pointer object is accessed using the variable name `Pile`.

The char pointer `Pile` can be used for accessing the individual bytes of `PileInts`. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int PileInts[1024];
    char *Pile = (char *)PileInts;

    PileInts[0] = 1;
    PileInts[1] = 2;

    // Print the bytes/chars of the first two ints of PileInts
    for (unsigned i= 0; i < (2 * sizeof PileInts[0]); ++i)
    {
        printf("0x%02x\n", *Pile); // Print what Pile points to
        ++Pile;                    // Increment Pile so it points to the next byte/char
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
0x01
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x02
0x00
0x00
0x00
```

Note: The output may differ from system to system due to different endianess and/or integer size.

If you want to see the value of `Pile`, i.e. the address it points to, you can change the code like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int PileInts[1024];
    char *Pile = (char *)PileInts;

    PileInts[0] = 1;
    PileInts[1] = 2;

    for (unsigned i= 0; i < (2 * sizeof PileInts[0]); ++i)
    {
        printf("Pile points to addresss %p where the value 0x%02x is stored\n", 
               (void*)Pile, *Pile);
        ++Pile;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
Pile points to addresss 0x7ffe5860b8e0 where the value 0x01 is stored
Pile points to addresss 0x7ffe5860b8e1 where the value 0x00 is stored
Pile points to addresss 0x7ffe5860b8e2 where the value 0x00 is stored
Pile points to addresss 0x7ffe5860b8e3 where the value 0x00 is stored
Pile points to addresss 0x7ffe5860b8e4 where the value 0x02 is stored
Pile points to addresss 0x7ffe5860b8e5 where the value 0x00 is stored
Pile points to addresss 0x7ffe5860b8e6 where the value 0x00 is stored
Pile points to addresss 0x7ffe5860b8e7 where the value 0x00 is stored
```

Comment: what am I able to do with Pile? I didn't really understand the purpose of pointers very well.

Comment: @4386427: Also it would be good if you can show the example code, with the address printed so that OP can know 1 byte address increments

Comment: @kevinmarks (**type is King!**) It controls pointer arithmetic. So say you use `int *p = PileInts;` and then advance the pointer `p` by one (`p = p + 1;`) since the pointer it type `int`, `p + 1` advances 4-bytes in memory to the next `int`. By casting to `char *`, the type of `Pile` is pointer to `char`. So if you advance `Pile`, e.g (`Pile = Pile + 1;`), now `Pile` points to the next **byte** in `PileInt`, not the next `int`.

Comment: @Inian Added example that prints the address as well

Comment: thanks a lot. I am getting it a little more now. I do have another question. I have this array organized as a 64x64 box, with a value in every location. How would I check to see if values are the same in some rows vertically?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks a lot. this information is very helpful. in my code, would there be any reason to cast Pile to a char since I already made it a char on the left side?

Comment: @kevinmarks I'm not sure what you mean by 64x64. The result of 64x64 is 4096 but your array is only 1024 ints. Anyway, if you need 64x64 why not do: `int box[64][64];`

Comment: @4386427 that's what I am wondering. I've got no clue why I would have a 1x1024 int array if I will be searching through a 64x64 box.

Comment: @kevinmarks As you iterate across your rows `x` and columns `y` (beginning at the second row and ending at last), you can check if value at `[x][y-1]` equals value at `[x][y]`. If it does, the value at that index is the same as the one above vertically. As to you second question, always compile with **warnings enabled** `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS (and don't accept code until it compiles without warning) -- without the cast -- you will receive a warning (you probably will by default).

Comment: why `(void*)Pile`, not just `Pile` at `printf`?

Comment: Because the C standard requires it and specifically states a mismatch between the conversion specifier `"%p"` (which requires type `void *`) and the argument (type `char *`) invokes *Undefined Behavior* -- Bad Juju... [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's the thing. If I had a 64x64 array I could do just that, but I only have a 1x1024 array and have no idea how to check that. In the writeup it says that every 8 bits is a color.

Comment: @user3365922 Because `%p` requires a `void*` so `Pile` must be cast'ed into `void*` before printing. If you don't, it will be undefined behavior according to the C standard. In the real world, it will however work fine even without the cast on most systems. But to be sure: do the cast

Comment: @kevinmarks I guess you have some assignment... It seems to be some "dirty" trick thing. On many systems `int` is 4 chars. So 1024 ints is 4096 chars which again is 64x64 chars. So it seems the idea is to use the 1024 ints as if it is 64x64 chars. Very ugly IMO.

Comment: @kevinmarks - I'll comment back under the original question

Comment: @4386427 use 1024 ints as if it were 64x64 chars, could you expand a little more on that? I think that is exactly what I am supposed to be doing but I cannot figure out how to think of a 1x1024 int array as a 64x64 array of chars

Comment: @kevinmarks Well, `*(Pile + 64*row + column)` will do that, i.e. read/write the char in position `(row, column)`

Comment: @4386427 thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

> line creates a character named `*Pile` that gives the value of the address at PileInts

No. It creates a pointer to character `char*` named `Pile`, which points to the lowest byte in the first `int` in an array of `int`-

> Could I get a deeper explanation?

The code gives a pointer which can be used to access individual bytes of the first `int` in the array, and from there, individual bytes of the next adjacent `int`, until the end of the array.

This is possible because when an array name is used in an expression, it "decays" into a pointer to the first element of that array. Making `PileInts`, when used in an array, equivalent to type `int*`.

Converting from `int*` to `char*` is valid but fishy C. Some things to be aware of:

- First of all, `uint8_t*` should be used whenever one seeks to access raw data values. The `char` type is highly problematic since it has implementation-defined signedness - it should not be used for anything else but for characters and strings. [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)
- This pointer will point at the *lowest address* of the first `int`. Which bytes this corresponds to is CPU-specific, namely it depends on *endianess* of the CPU. Using bitwise shift operators instead of pointers would have remove this CPU dependency, so depending on what you want to do with this pointer, it may or may not be the right tool for the task.

As for the pointer conversion itself, it is fine as per C17 6.3.2.3/7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
>   resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is
>   undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer.

Meaning that something like `(int*) ((char*)PileInts + 1)` would be an undefined behavior bug, because the `int*` will be misaligned.

The same paragraph in the standard continues:

> When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
>   the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

This is the rule allowing us to iterate over any data type by using a character pointer (or preferably the equivalent `uint8_t*`). The same is *not* true for any other pointer type, we could for example *not* use a `short*` to do the same, thinking we iterate over 16 bit words.

There's also another rule preventing us from using any other pointer type, namely the rule regulating the compiler's internal type system and how different pointers may be an alias of each other. Informally known as [the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). This rule too has an exception for character types only. Meaning we *can't* do this:

```
int PileInts[1024];
char *Pile = (char *)PileInts;
short* sptr = (short*)Pile; // very questionable cast but not a bug yet
printf("%h", *sptr); // bug, data is accessed as wrong type, strict aliasing violation
```